# ASP.NET Draw some points on Image and Get coordination

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress, components

I'm a beginner of C#/ASP.NET

Could you please recommend some components for me?

-Here is my scenario.

1. Load an image file on page.
2. Add some points(just circle shape) on the image.
3. Move these points on image.
4. Get coordination(x, y) of points.
5. Store the coordination to database.

which component is appropriate for this web page?

It doen't matter using standard asp.net component or devexpress component.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jquery draggable object to implement this.

Here is the link about draggable object.

http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-getting-the-coordinates-of-a-draggable-object/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **HTML 5 Canvas** [drawImage](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-load-image-data-url/) + [getMousePos](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/)